# HTML input tag con type=password

Tags: html, input

Tengo la siguiente definición de inputs en el documento html:

```
<div id="contenedor_credenciales" class="contenedor_evento_seleccionado" align="center">

  <h1 align="center">Ingrese credenciales para acceder al sitio</h1>
  <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="usuario" class="input_tex"/>

  <input type="password" value="secret" name="contraseña" id="contraseña" placeholder="contraseña" class="input_tex"/>

  <button id="btn_ingresar" " >Ingresar</button>

</div>
```

El problema es que el password me muestra lo que estoy escribiendo cuando ingreso a la página cuando la misma está subida al servidor (cuando ingreso al servidor a través del dominio). No así cuando abro el documento html desde el disco de mi PC (es decir, cuando abro el documento sin subirlos al servidor.

Comment: No hay razon para que el input password se muestre visible, a menos que haya algun script o complemento que cambie el type="password" a type="text". Intenta en una ventana de incognito u otro browser para ver que pasa.

Comment: No veo problema, pero... Te sugiero que quites el `value="secret"` eso solo lo que agrega es un texto en el `input` Lo no veo es que no esta dentro de un `form` y no tienes el `botton` tipo `submit`. De lo contrario vas bien.

Comment: Inspeccionalo como está cuando está subido al servidor, como te dicen puede haber algo que lo modifique.

Comment: Ya no entendí entonces cuál fue la solución?, Por qué entonces la pregunta quedará cerrada por qué no es reproducible el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                        <div id="contenedor_credenciales" 
              class="contenedor_evento_seleccionado" >

           <h1>Ingrese credenciales para acceder al sitio</h1>
             <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="usuario" 
          class="input_tex"/>

           <input type="password" value="secret" name="contraseña" id="contraseña" 
      placeholder="contraseña" class="input_tex"/>

            <button id="btn_ingresar"  >Ingresar</button>

           </div>
```

Amigo no veo ningún problema en tu codigo, lo probé y no me da el problema que dices tener, deberías checar si estás llamando el formulario correcto y también por ahí se te escapó una comilla doble